# how do you configure ubuntu to run only with tor

Tags: ssh, tor, port-forwarding

I have a problem. I'm trying to port forward and get a similar error msg, I type this in:`ssh -N -L 9050:10.0.2.2:9050 root@10.0.3.1` and then I get this msg:`ssh: connect to host 10.0.3.1 port 22: No route to host`. I've been googling around a couple of days and I can't seem to find anything that directly relates to this, I'm also a noob so there could be something sitting right in front of my face lol. Either way I came across this post and thought I'd drop a line, I hope someone out there can help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you ssh to 10.0.3.1 at all without port forwarding? This seems to be your issue that needs solving first.

Comment: Is this inside a VM?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!